# Change color on plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to change the color of my scattlerplot, but i still getting the default schema.

```
import plotly.express as px

mycolour = ['#FF5733', '#33FF57', '#3357FF']

fig = px.scatter(SandiaA, x="Semana", y="PrecioPromedio", color="Anio",
                 color_discrete_sequence=mycolour)


fig.show()
```

Any advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The graph will be created in the color you specify. I tried it with the following code What version of plotly are you currently using? I am on the latest version 5.15.0. `df = px.data.iris();mycolour = ['#FF5733', '#33FF57', '#3357FF'];fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", color_discrete_sequence=mycolour)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the color of the marker you should use `marker_color` option. You can actually set different colors for different data series.
You can check the docs right here: https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter#style-scatter-plots